# Types redefinition and cast

Tags: types, casting, ocaml

For a school project about Von Neumman automaton in OCaml I define the types `state` as a sum type taking values `Alive` or `Dead`, I also have a type `generation` which is simply a `state array array`.

In a function I generate a `state array array` using `make_matrix` with a default `state` value. I want that function to return a `generation` so I casted the function return value with something like

```
let myfoo args : generation = ...
```

The problem is that ocaml don't wan't to cast the `state array array`generated by `make_matrix`.

How can I return an automaton when I manipulate a `state array array`which is the same thing for me ?

I would like to let ocaml know that all the `state array array`I manipulate are of type `generation.`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little difficult to understand. Here are some comments.

First, OCaml doesn't have "type casting" in the sense of mainstream languages. It's a strongly typed language, where every expression has a type that is known in its entirety. When you specify the type of some expression:

```
let f (x: int) (y: int) : int = x + y
```

The types you supply are much more like comments than coercions. They are mostly a way to tell the human reader what the types are, not the compiler. (You can use these annotations to *narrow* a type, but that's a separate discussion.)

Second, when you declare a type like this:

```
type generation = state array array
```

the name `generation` is just a synonym for the type `state array array`. In other words, it doesn't create a new type. It just creates a shorter name for an existing type.

So, when OCaml shows the type of something it has to select among all the available names for the type. Sometimes it will take the longer name (`state array array`) and sometimes the shorter (`generation`) depending on a heuristic that tries to do what it thinks you would like. But sometimes it's wrong (not about the type, but about what you would like :-).

Comment: Thank you, I knew this but I just didn't express myself correctly, and
what I called 'cast' is a total abuse of language so sorry for haven't been clearer.

I to tell OCaml  that function needs to return a `generation`but I need a trick to let him see that `state array array`as a `generation`.

It's not a super idea to have that type because it's a source of problem but it's part of the subject so...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jeffrey's answer few comments that might help you:

1. If you annotated your function like this, `let myfoo args : generation = ...`, and compiler complains saying that the return type is different, then it means that the there is an error in your function and it indeed doesn't return a generation or `state array array`.
2. There is no need to prove somehow to a compiler, that `state array array` is the same as `generation`, because as soon as you added the type equation of the form `type generation = state array array` it knows this. It is an axiom. But take a note, that the `=` is reflexive, so for a compiler this equation means that `generation` is a `state array array` and vice verse, the `state array array` is a `generation`. So it may use this types interchangeably.
3. If you want to create a real new type, instead of type aliasing, that you're using, then you need to define new type and use it. In your case you can define a new type as follows:

   ```
   type generation = Gen of state array array
   ```

   and the `Gen` would be a constructor that will take a `state array array` and create a value of type `generation`, like this:

   ```
    let generation = Gen xs
   ```

   where `xs` is a value of type `state array array`.

Comment: Ok sorry guys everything was right and I have just forgotten that I change the type generation to `None | Gen of state array array` so it couldn't work without the constructor.
Sorry for the disturbance and thank you all.